# Issue with selection of template specialization involving auto argument and temporary object

Tags: c++, templates, auto, temporary

Given the following code, with a specialization of a template function with an auto argument...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void f(auto val);

template<>
void f<int>(const std::string&) { std::cout << "ok\n"; }

int main() {
    f<int, const std::string&>("xxx");  // ok
    // f<int>("xxx");                   // won't compile    

    f<int, const std::string&>(std::string("xxx"));  // ok
    // f<int>(std::string("xxx"));                   // won't compile
}
```

Why can't the compiler (GCC w/ C++17 in this case) select the specialization without explicit specification of the auto argument type?

Comment: There are no `auto` function parameters in C++17.